# Swift/FireStore - Best way to querying by date

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

OK, so this isn't as technical as you may think. I am wondering, if I was to add a record to FireStore which format would be the best means of doing so, which would allow me to query data via date and month as well as just the month? Would I have two different nodes? i.e. `formattedMonthString` and `formattedDateString`

So in essence my database would look like

```
formattedMonthString: "May"
formattedDateString: "21 May 2021"
```

Or would I be better to use a `Date()`. This isn't a TimeStamp, rather I would select the date and and upload it to FireStore.

Of course then I could do a query such as .whereField("formattedMonthString", isEqualTo: "May"), however, I doubt I could do a range filter on `formattedDateString` i.e. 21 May 2021, 22 May 2021 et al.

I hope I explained it well enough, apologies if it isn't as technical as other questions.

Comment: Querying by month is simple, just dedicate a field to month and do a string-equals query on it. This would return every document of a particular month regardless of year, however. I assume you've accounted for this already, though. "Querying by date" is ambiguous. How do you want to query by date exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can query with values that equal a direct string equivalent but you cannot sort by since the months are not alphanumerically in order. You should find the basic query to suit your needs for the month or date respectfully

```js
let query = FirestoreRef.whereField("formattedMonthString", isEqualTo: "May")
let query = FirestoreRef.whereField("formattedDateString", isEqualTo: "21 May 2021")
```

You can read more about simple queries here

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries